# Objective C inheritance and syntax

Tags: objective-c

I am starting to learn basic of Objective-C, currently reading Kochan's (Progamming Objective C).

I am stucked at Inheritance topic.

I have 2 Class and 1 subClass, XYPoint and Rectangle, Square (Square is subclass of Rectangle).

I have method which can retain value X and Y coordinate for Rectangle Object.

here is my main.m files

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Rectangle.h"
#import "Square.h"
#import "XYPoint.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        Square *square1 = [[Square alloc]init];
        XYPoint *myPoint = [[XYPoint alloc]init];

        [myPoint setX:33 andY:33];

        [square1 setOrigin:myPoint];

        [myPoint setX:25 andY:25];
        NSLog(@"square1 origin is %i and %i",[[square1 origin]x],[[square1 origin]y]);
        [myPoint setX:125 andY:125];

        NSLog(@"square1 origin is %i and %i",[[square1 origin]x],[[square1 origin]y]);

        [myPoint setX:25 andY:25];
        NSLog(@"square1 origin is %i and %i",[[square1 origin]x],[[square1 origin]y]);


    }
    return 0;
}
```

and my Rectangle.m

```
-(void) setOrigin:(XYPoint *)pt{


       if (!origin)
        origin = [[XYPoint alloc]init];

        origin.x = pt.x;
        origin.y = pt.y;

}

-(XYPoint *)origin {
    return  origin;
}
```

and XYPoint.m files

```
- (void) setX:(int)xVal andY: (int) yVal{


    x = xVal;
    y = yVal;

}
```

Output from this Program is :

```
2014-01-23 15:25:36.368 Rectangle1[4356:303] square1 origin is 33 and 33
2014-01-23 15:25:36.370 Rectangle1[4356:303] square1 origin is 33 and 33
2014-01-23 15:25:36.370 Rectangle1[4356:303] square1 origin is 33 and 33
```

NSLogged 3 times. this retain method  `-(void) setOrigin:(XYPoint *)pt;`
helped to retain XY values on Rectangle Object even XY value reseted through setX andY method.

but when I changed retain method into this :

-(void) setOrigin:(XYPoint *)pt{

```
       if (!origin)
        origin = [[XYPoint alloc]init];

        origin = pt;
}
```

NSLogged output changed into this :

```
2014-01-23 15:29:54.287 Rectangle1[4398:303] square1 origin is 25 and 25
2014-01-23 15:29:54.288 Rectangle1[4398:303] square1 origin is 125 and 125
2014-01-23 15:29:54.289 Rectangle1[4398:303] square1 origin is 25 and 25
```

what is the difference between those two ? aren't those two have the same characteristic pointing at the same coordinate both for x and y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because You're creating an origin with the name  **myPoint** using the following :

```
[myPoint setX:33 andY:33];
```

And then you're making the myPoint as origin of square 1using :

```
[square1 setOrigin:myPoint];
```

And then you're changing the co-ordinates of square using the statements:

```
[myPoint setX:25 andY:25];
[myPoint setX:125 andY:125];
[myPoint setX:25 andY:25];
```

When you change the values and then try to print the origin using the

```
[[square1 origin]x];
[[square1 origin]y];
```

You'll get the modified values because when you say :

```
[origin x]; // it points to myPoint.x which u r changing all the time.
```

and

```
[origin Y]; // it points to myPoint.y which u r changing all the time.
```

Finally you are getting the right output . Please analyse the code properly.

**EDIT:** You have gone wrong in defining:

```
-(void) setOrigin:(XYPoint *)pt;
```

when you do this :

```
-(void) setOrigin:(XYPoint *)pt{
    if (!origin){
            origin = [[XYPoint alloc]init];

            origin = pt;// makes origin.X to point to pt.x and origin.Y to point to pt.y
   }
}
```

you're just making **origin** point to **pt** (which is myPoint), i.e, **origin is nothing but a pointer to pt** ,so when myPoint's X and Y value changes. Your origin.x and origin.y changes. **This is a shallow copy**.

But when we do this :

```
-(void) setOrigin:(XYPoint *)pt{
if (!origin){
origin = [[XYPoint alloc]init];
origin.x = pt.x;// copies value in pt.x to origin.x, so when pt.x changes origin.x doesn't change
origin.y = pt.y;// copies value in pt.y to origin.y, so when pt.y changes origin.y doesn't change
}

    }
```

We're acheiving a **Deep Copy**, which means whenever mypoint.x and mypoint.y changes our origin.x and origin.y doesn't change.

Comment: Oh i see now, so there is a huge differences between origin = pt and origin.x = pt.x. While origin = pt is used to point to address value, and origin.x = pt.x is used to store pt.x value into origin.x , But what is the purpose of ! (negation) on if (!origin) do?  is  it one time only function , to check origin exist or not?

Comment: Yes . when you say `origin = pt;` **address** of **pt(i.e, myPoint)** is assigned to Origin. When u say `origin.x = pt.x` the values are being assigned here not the address .

Comment: I have also studied Stephen's book. If u go little further he has explained this with neat diagrams too.